# Jenkins Build Pipeline fileLoad in library files not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the [Workflow Remote Loader](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin) plugin's `fileLoad` function to load dependencies for my build script. In my main file, I have the following:

build-app.groovy

```
def java
def util

node {
    stage "Setup"
    fileLoader.withGit('git@github.com:myorg/build-scripts.git', 'master', '234720asdf8ed1a2', '') {

        java = fileLoader.load('lib/java.groovy');
        util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy');
    }

    util.checkIfFileExists('myFile.txt')
    def version = java.getJarVersion("api")
}
```

`util.checkIfFileExists()` works perfectly, but a problem occurs when `java.getJarVersion` is called. In `getJarVersion` there is also a dependency on `util`. My java lib is as follows:

java.groovy

```
def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')

def getJarVersion() {
    ...
    util.checkIfFileExists('myFile.txt')
    ...
}
```

This gives the following error when I run in Jenkins:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: util for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:23)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:17)
    at Script4.checkIfFileExists(Script4.groovy:39)
    at Script4.getJarVersion(Script4.groovy:23)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:18)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:183)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The plugin's doc says:

> Use static initializers within the Groovy file of the loaded file to
>   load more context from neighbor files.

I've tried `static def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')`, but this produced the same error. I've also tried a variety of other combinations to no avail. Maybe this is some lack of understanding of the groovy language? Not really sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `@groovy.transform.Field def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')`

Comment: Just tried this and now `java.getJarVersion` can't be called from my main build file (original post updated to show how it's called): `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'getJarVersion' found`

Comment: If _static initializer_ in Groovy is the same as in Java then it's not declaring a variable _static_ as with `static def util`. It's an abbreviation for [_Static Initialization Block_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: I've also tried a block: `static { def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy') }` and the compiler complains when the Jenkins job runs: `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script4.groovy: 1: unexpected token: static @ line 1, column 1.
   static {`

Comment: @threejeez not sure what you mean wrt the `@Field` annotation...

Comment: @tim_yates I changed the line in my `java` lib as you suggested. When I did that, I could no longer call functions in `java` lib from my main build file. The script would fail at `java.getJarVersion("api")` with the exception `NoSuchMethodError`. Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after much trial and error, I figured out the issue.

java.groovy before:

```
def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')

def getJarVersion() {
    ...
    util.checkIfFileExists('myFile.txt')
    ...
}

return this;
```

java.groovy after:

```
def getJarVersion() {
    ...
    util.checkIfFileExists('myFile.txt')
    ...
}

this.util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')
return this;
```

The `return this;` line was omitted from the original post because it was in the documentation of the remote file loader plugin, but it's key. When java.groovy is loaded from build.groovy it is using the returned `this` as the scope the calls made to `java.groovy`. This scope did not include `util` when it was defined as `def util = fileLoader.load('lib/util.groovy')`. Adding it to this before returning it put util in scope for all function calls in the file.

Answer (score 4):

For those coming here from Google on a similar error message, you have to install the Pipeline Remote Loader plugin. Otherwise it will give you:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fileLoader for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```